# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE. while adding a field

Tags: php, laravel, web, routes, laravel-7

So I am learning laravel and I have a problem. I have projects and tasks within a project.
So I am adding the project tasks on the same page to **show** the project. I get this problem whenever I try to add a task

[An image of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UulB6.png)

[An image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLcam.png)


The error:

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

The web route:

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
Route::resource('projects/{project}/tasks', 'ProjectTaskController');
```

Route list:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                  | Name             | Action                                             | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                    |                  | Closure                                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                             |                  | Closure                                            | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects                             | projects.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index      | web          |
|        | POST      | projects                             | projects.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store      | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/create                      | projects.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}                   | projects.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@show       | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | projects/{project}                   | projects.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@update     | web          |
|        | DELETE    | projects/{project}                   | projects.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@destroy    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}/edit              | projects.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@edit       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}/tasks             | tasks.index      | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | projects/{project}/tasks             | tasks.store      | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}/tasks/create      | tasks.create     | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}/tasks/{task}      | tasks.show       | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | projects/{project}/tasks/{task}      | tasks.update     | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | projects/{project}/tasks/{task}      | tasks.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects/{project}/tasks/{task}/edit | tasks.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectTaskController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

The form that adds a task:

```
<form method="POST" action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks" class="box" >
        @csrf
        <div class="field">
            <label for="description" class="label">New Task</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="description" placeholder="New Task">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Add Task</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The store method in the **ProjectTaskController**

```
    public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        Task::create([
            'project_id' => $project->id,
            'description' => 'description'
        ]);
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: You are calling POST on projects/6 which is not correct it should be projects/6/tasks, the form seems correct thou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that there are fields that I am trying to fill that are not added to the  **$fillable** variable.

Before:

```
protected $fillable = ['completed'];
```

After:

```
protected $fillable = ['completed','project_id','description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the tasks route above the projects route. Currently, `/projects` is matching all wildcard `/project/*` routes, which means it won't get to the Tasks route.

```
Route::resource('projects/{project}/tasks', 'ProjectTaskController');
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

Comment: The problem was because of the $fillable variable. I have fixed it (without changing the order of the routes) and everything is working as it should be. So I don't think the order makes any difference. Moreover, I think that the ```/projects```  is only matching the wildcards mentioned in the route list and not ```/projects/*```.

Comment: The fillable makes no sense for the error message, but if it's working, then great.